# Is data augmentation in Keras applied to the validation set when using ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a deep neural network using `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory` in Keras. Data is in one folder. Therefore, I am using `validation_split=0.x` when creating a generator using `ImageDataGenerator`. I then create two flows, one for training and one for validation using `flow_from_directory` with `subset="training"` and `subset="validation"` respectively.

I am wondering if any specified image augmentation (transformation) when creating the `ImageDataGenerator` is applied to both training and validation subsets or only the training one.

I can't find the right section in the Keras repository in GitHub to check it.

(Note: I know it's a better practice to have two separate directories for training and validation with two separate generators)

Code Example:

```
img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.2,horizontal_flip = True, vertical_flip = True,...)
train_flow = img_gen.flow_from_directory('directory',subset = "training",...)
validation_flow = img_gen.flow_from_directory('directory',subset = "validation",...)
history=model.fit_generator(generator = train_flow ,validation_data = validation_flow,...)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory for both training and validation sets, will also augment the validation data. This is shown in the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class), which states under Image Generator Methods flow_from_directory: Takes data & label arrays, generates batches of augmented data.
If you do not want to use data augmentation on the validation set, you can look at the provided example:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Note: In this case, you could also pass the rescaled validation data directly, without using a generator, e.g.:
`validation_data=(x_valid, y_valid)`

Comment: Thanks @mgross but the documentation is not clear when it comes to the new feature which is `validation_split` in  `ImageDataGenerator` it doesn't say clearly if the transformation is applied to both training and validation subsets. That's why I was trying to find the implementation in the Keras repository in GitHub

Comment: @sidrat28: Did you check [image.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image.py)? I think this confirms that data augmentation is both applied to the validation and the training set the way you are using it in your code example, as both subsets are treated the same way.

Comment: It might be confusing to use test and validation as synonyms, I would stick to `validation_datagen` and `validation_generator` and reserve 'test' for your blind data.

Comment: @jorijnsmit: You are right and I wondered why I wrote it like this, until I looked up https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class, where it is also mixed up.

Comment: So you have to create the validation split manually? That renders `validation_split` useless in this scenario, right?

Comment: What about testing the model on new data? What if the accuracy falls when applied to non augmented data?

Comment: The asker mentions he does not have the train and validation data in separate directories, so this solution wouldn't work. Also, the documentation doesn't explicitly specify if the augmentations necessarily apply to the validation subset.

Comment: @Elegant Code You are right, interesting I did not notice at the time. I might update the answer, but I did not use keras recently. So you could also propose a better answer.

Comment: @mgross , no problem. I'll be happy to upvote your answer when you update it. That's how our collective knowledge improves :)